# Help with C# LINQ Projection

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, linq-to-entities, projection

I have a `IQueryable<SomePOCO>` (a LINQ-Entities query, if that matters):

```
public class SomePOCO
{
   public string ParentName { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

And i'm trying to *project* to a single object (anonymous type would be best, since i only need method scope) which has 2 properties:

```
public string ParentName { get; set; }
public ICollection<SimplePoco> { get; set;
```

SimplePOCO is as follows:

```
public class SimplePOCO
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

The reason i'm doing this is that all of the "SomePOCO"s im retrieving have the same ParentName, so i just want that once, as opposed to bringing over the wire the same value N amount of times and doing a `.First()`.

Hope that makes sense.

The end result is i should be able to do this:

```
var parentName = result.ParentName; // string
var pocos = result.SimplePOCOs; // ICollection<SimplePOCO>
```

I think i either need some kind of aggregation, like with `GroupBy` or `SelectMany`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Interestingly, GroupBy is for projecting from a flag structure to a hierarchical structure - SelectMany will project a nested structure to a flat structure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you just need to do a group by Parent Name

```
var result = collection.GroupBy(i => i.ParentName)
           .Select(g => new {
                                ParentName = g.Key, 
                                SimplePocos = g.Select(i => new SimplePoco
                                                                {
                                                                 Name = i.Name, 
                                                                 Url = i.Url
                                                                 })
                              });
```

Comment: Nice. Just added a `.SingleOrDefault()` at the end to materalize the query. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is the first step.

```
var groups = myQ.GroupBy(p => p.ParentName);
```

You will need to have your middle data structure. I'll call it `Grouping`.

```
var myList = new List<Grouping>();

foreach (var group in groups) {
   var newGrouping = new Grouping();
   new Grouping.ParentName = group.Key;
   newGrouping.SimplePocos = group.Select(p => new SimplePoco(p)).ToArray();
 }
```

You should have a constructor of `SimplePoco` that will convert it for you.

Comment: This would work too, but giving the answer off to @Bala R since he got in first. +1 for the answer.